# sandbox and quality control

Tags: discussion, feature-request, sandbox

At time of posting: the front page of recent questions had 15 questions total. 6 of those were either on hold, closed or in negative and probably flagged.

Consequently, I am suggesting a meta sandbox thread for people to post their questions - that they can be altered and made more suitable before being posted to the main IPS site.

My main concern is that the questions that seem to get closed tend to be new users, and there are existing guidelines on what is / isn't on topic for this site - they don't have enough reputation to participate in the meta where the sandbox should be. The alternative seems to be to put the sandbox on the main IPS, but that feels wrong.

looking for cnc on this suggestion and alternative viewpoints on this "issue"

Comment: It exists on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?s=1|137.8049

Comment: @gparyani that appears to be mostly for testing formatting? or am i missing something?

Comment: What does "cnc" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a "sandbox" post on the main site; it would be an off-topic question, and it would have to be exempted from the rules. In the words of another wise user I know, special casing *sucks*. Also, if anyone answers or edits there, it will bump the post to the front page. We don't want that.

Yes, it would be ideal to have a sandbox post here on the meta site, but we can't do that because new users can't participate here. If one wants to learn how to *format* their posts, there exists a sandbox on Meta Stack Exchange, which doesn't require rep for participation: [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).